# How do I add a random string to a URL to prevent caching if a question mark already exists?

Tags: url, random, apache-flex

I need to launch a random URL through Flex in order to prevent caching.

The current URL ends in `/?propertyID=Neighborhood1&planCode=StreetScene`

I can usually add a `+ ("?"+Math.random().toString());` to make it random, but that doesn't work at all in this case.

Is that because a question mark already exists? What is the best way to append a random string to override caching in this case? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass several parameters in an URL you do that with "?" for the first one and "&" for the rest:

```
"/?propertyID=Neighborhood1&planCode=StreetScene&random=" + Math.random().toString();
```